# Scriptaulous JS not being called

Tags: javascript

Trying to use Scriptaculous to reveal details of an event on a click.

I've called the relevant files

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css" />
<script src="java/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="java/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And I want to use this button to call the details

```
<a href="#" onclick="Effect.BlindDown('eventdetails'); return false;"><img class="open" src="./img/plus.png"></a>
```

And I've hidden the eventdetails div inline

```
<div id="eventdetails" style="display:none;">
```

The cursor hover shows that the link is working, but no movement of any kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the prototype line above scriptaculous; Scriptaculous relies on Prototype.